# How to add additional functionality to a keybinding in VSCode without overriding the original functionality?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to scroll down a line along with the insertion of new line character when <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. After adding this to `keybindings.json`,

```json
    {
        "key": "enter",
        "command": "scrollLineDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```

I can only scroll down a line when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. How can I prevent it from overriding the original action?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a command `-scrollLineDown` in your keybindings.json?  If you change the keybinding from the KeyBoard Shortcuts UI, instead of manually like just adding your keybinding to keybindings.json, an additional command will be automatically entered by vscode removing the original keybinding.  So look for a `"command": "-scrollLineDown" in your keybindings.json, with the `-` preceding the command, and remove it.  I tested it and both the orignal and your keybinding work.

Comment: I never removed anything from the KeyBoard Shortcuts UI therefore there is no such entry with `"command": "-scrollLineDown"`. But how did you made it work? I had to use `multi-command` extension for it.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your keybinding into my keybindings.json.  And both `Ctrl+downarrow` and `Enter` work to scroll down - is that what you want?  Did you actually do a find in your keybindings.json for `-scrollLineDown`?  And make sure you do not have another `enter` key binding for something else.

Comment: Were you able to both insert a new line character and scroll down simultaneously?
Yes I did search for `-scrollLineDown` and I even don't have another key binding for `enter` key.

Comment: No, I wasn't sure what you meant by keep the "original action", which is why I asked if you wanted both scrolldowns to work - I thought you wanted the original keybinding to still work.  For what you do want - two commands triggered at once - I do think you will need a macro solution.